# Вставить объект в конец массива

Tags: php, laravel

```
class RegionResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'            => $this->id,
            'name'          => $this->name,
            'branches'      => $this->branches,
        ];
    }
}
```

В Laravel Resource возвращается коллекция с данными, можно ли в конец общего массива добавить еще один объект с данными, к примеру сейчас возвращается

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Московская область",
    "branches": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Академия футбола"
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Школа футбола"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Рязанская область",
    "branches": [
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Академія Луцьк"
      },
      {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Школа Луцьк"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Вот в конец массива добавить еще один объект и в итоге получить вот такой массив

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Московская область",
    "branches": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Академия футбола"
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Школа футбола"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Рязанская область",
    "branches": [
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Академія Луцьк"
      },
      {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Школа Луцьк"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
       "id": 666,
       "name": "Общий объект"
   }
]
```

Comment: `$array[] = $object` запретили?

Comment: Можете на примере ? не совсем понимаю решение

Comment: данный метод у вас экспортирует один элемент этого массива. не на данном уровне решать вопрос надо. Вообще это вопрос бизнес-логики скорее. Получили свой массив, добавили туда, вернули.

Comment: Это и есть пример. Адаптируй его под свой код.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге в конец массива или в конец коллекции? Если коллекции, то $array->push($element);